# Compare two columns of a collection in laravel?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-7

I want to compare two columns of a collection.I don't want to do this in db level, only in collection level.

I have a collection like this (I returned it in array model for readability)

```
   array:3 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "total_amount" => 200000.0

    "admin_max_amount" => "200000000"


  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "total_amount" => 100000.0

    "admin_max_amount" => "200000000"


  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "total_amount" => 100000.0

    "admin_max_amount" => "0"

  ]
]
```

I want to get first of them where total_amount > admin_max_amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more 'Laravel' way to do it:

```
$items = collect([
    [
        "total_amount" => 200000.0,

        "admin_max_amount" => "200000000",
    ],
    [
        "total_amount"     => 100000.0,
        "admin_max_amount" => "200000000",
    ],
    [
        "total_amount"     => 100000.0,
        "admin_max_amount" => "0",
    ],
]);
$result = $items->first(function ($item)
{
    return (float)$item['total_amount'] > (float)$item['admin_max_amount'];
});
dump($result);
```